# Seeding a mysql db with testcontainers

Tags: java, mysql, testcontainers

I have a very simple situation: an existing mysql database in AWS that I want to test against using testcontainers.

I have followed the official guideline (https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/) and its examples (https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/master/modules/jdbc-test/src/test/java/org/testcontainers/junit/SimpleMySQLTest.java), however I am not able to do load the dump created with mysqldump.

Every time I got the following error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

As suggested by other users, I have tried the following:

```
MySQLContainer mysql = (MySQLContainer) new MySQLContainer()
                .withInitScript("foodmart_department.sql")
                .withUsername("root")
                .withPassword("test")
                .withLogConsumer(new Slf4jLogConsumer(logger));
        mysql.start();
```

But it hangs for minutes and terminates with this error:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

        ℹ︎ Checking the system...
        ✔ Docker version should be at least 1.6.0
        ✔ Docker environment should have more than 2GB free disk space


org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed

    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:307)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:287)
    at com.Foodmart.testSimple(Foodmart.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:628)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:117)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:184)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:180)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:127)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.rnorth.ducttape.RetryCountExceededException: Retry limit hit with exception
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:88)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:300)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Could not create/start container
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:418)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.lambda$doStart$0(GenericContainer.java:302)
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:81)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: org.testcontainers.ext.ScriptUtils$UncategorizedScriptException: Failed to execute database script from resource [-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 8.0.19, for osx10.14 (x86_64)
--
-- Host: mysql-technical-test.cq5i4y35n9gg.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com    Database: foodmart
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.7.26-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
SET @MYSQLDUMP_TEMP_LOG_BIN = @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN;
SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN= 0;

--
-- GTID state at the beginning of the backup
--

SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED=/*!80000 '+'*/ '';

--
-- Table structure for table `department`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `department`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `department` (
  `department_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `department_description` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `i_department_id` (`department_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `department`
--

LOCK TABLES `department` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `department` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `department` VALUES (1,'HQ General Management'),(2,'HQ Information Systems'),(3,'HQ Marketing'),(4,'HQ Human Resources'),(5,'HQ Finance and Accounting'),(11,'Store Management'),(14,'Store Information Systems'),(15,'Permanent Checkers'),(16,'Temp Checkers'),(17,'Permanent Stockers'),(18,'Temp Stockers'),(19,'Store Permanent Butchers');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `department` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
]
    at org.testcontainers.ext.ScriptUtils.executeDatabaseScript(ScriptUtils.java:375)
    at org.testcontainers.ext.ScriptUtils.executeDatabaseScript(ScriptUtils.java:313)
    at org.testcontainers.ext.ScriptUtils.runInitScript(ScriptUtils.java:302)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.JdbcDatabaseContainer.runInitScriptIfRequired(JdbcDatabaseContainer.java:240)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.JdbcDatabaseContainer.containerIsStarted(JdbcDatabaseContainer.java:154)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:403)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: org.testcontainers.exception.ConnectionCreationException: Could not obtain JDBC connection
    at org.testcontainers.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseDelegate.createNewConnection(JdbcDatabaseDelegate.java:34)
    at org.testcontainers.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseDelegate.createNewConnection(JdbcDatabaseDelegate.java:17)
    at org.testcontainers.delegate.AbstractDatabaseDelegate.getConnection(AbstractDatabaseDelegate.java:23)
    at org.testcontainers.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseDelegate.execute(JdbcDatabaseDelegate.java:42)
    at org.testcontainers.delegate.AbstractDatabaseDelegate.execute(AbstractDatabaseDelegate.java:34)
    at org.testcontainers.ext.ScriptUtils.executeDatabaseScript(ScriptUtils.java:362)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not create new connection
    at org.testcontainers.containers.JdbcDatabaseContainer.createConnection(JdbcDatabaseContainer.java:210)
    at org.testcontainers.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseDelegate.createNewConnection(JdbcDatabaseDelegate.java:31)
    ... 66 more
```

So, I am definitely doing something wrong to achieve something so simple.

Comment: Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: INSERT command denied to user 'test'@'172.17.0.1' for table 'department'

Comment: Forgot to mention: it is just a pure java application with maven. No Spring framework support.

Comment: There seems to be issue with MysqlContainer, I am facing the same issue and found this particular issue https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/2878, have you found solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's mysql, remove `.withUsername("root")`.

From the container's log:

`2020-10-08 12:35:53+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating user root ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 1: Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'%'`